# Logstash is not shipping logs to ElasticSearch when run as a service

Tags: logstash, puppet, elastic-stack

I am launching a new instance through AWS and I am using Puppet as the configuration management tool. I am using ELK Stack for the analytic purposes. So I am configuring Puppet in such a way that whenever I'm launching a new server, it will automatically install Logstash. So everything is setup properly now, I can see the Logstash service running, but the problem is that the logs are not getting shipped to ElasticSearch.

And there is more to it.

If I run the following command manually, I can see the logs getting shipped to elasticsearch.

`/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf`

Comment: Have you checked the logs for logstash and elasticsearch in /var/log?

Comment: Yes I have checked it. The problem was I was running the above command as a root user. The service being run as the respective logstash user. Now it is working fine.